# Windows 10 disable language panel on language switch

Tags: windows-10, language

After one of recent updates (I guess the May one) I've started seeing language panel in the right middle of the screen when I switch language.

[image]

I don't want to see it, because it's annoying and sometimes interfere with other keystrokes and language doesn't change. How can I disable it?

I didn't find how I can disable it or even how I can name it...

Comment: In *Settings > Devices > Typing > Advances keyboard settings > Language bar options*, try to set "Language Bar" to Hidden.

Comment: Doesn't change anything